# Tools to convert html layouts to Silverlight 3.0

Tags: html, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0, xaml-tools

I have a couple of applications for clients that were dragged into the web kicking and screaming.  I'd like to take a crack at moving some to Silverlight 3.0 if even just as a proof of concept exercise.  I'd like to see if I could make them full apps, layout and all.  I think the layout of the web app along w/ the graphics is good and don't want to lose that aspect.

Which leads to my question, are there tools to convert existing HTML/graphics to Xaml?  I'd rather use SL 3.0 navigation and not embed Silverlight xaps on every page as I would have to do w/ an ASP.NET MVC / Silverlight type solution.

Thanks.

Comment: You can re-use bitmap graphics, but all the better if you can find new art in Illustrator format and convert it to Xaml in Blend 3.  I'm interested to see if anyone has HTML conversion ideas, I don't know of any.

Comment: Honestly I hope this never gets written. Talk about a giant step backwards for web accessibility.

Comment: This wasn't a question asking for an opinion.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a related in spirit question after doing some research I can pretty confidently say no.  There are some tools for Silverlight 1.0 and 2.0 you can find with a simple google search ( terms: html to xaml converter) but nothing specifically for Silverlight 3.0

The xaml exporter for [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/design/Fireworks_XAML_Exporter.aspx) may be helpful if you've used Fireworks to design your sites, if not you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Having just gone through this (existing ASP.NET to Silverlight 3), I’d recommend against any attempt to automatically convert the layouts. With Silverlight having a very discrete set of controls and layout mechanisms compared to ASP.NET I’d be very surprised is any tool did a neat translation. Tools for auto-generating code (be it XAML or HTML) tend to create pretty sub-optimal syntax (Expression Design -> XAML comes to mind). If you were successful, you’d still need to consider the entire data access pattern which will also drive the structure of your XAML.

Comment: I think you're getting asp.net confused with HTML layout and graphics. I plan on rewriting the entire UI code base to use navigation and remove all dependencies on ASP.NET, but I'm not an artist and would basically have to repay an artist to convert the HTML layout to Xaml (assuming I can find one).  For a proof of concept, I just wanted something that looked close to the original to show the client.

Comment: It's the same end result whether you're converting directly from ASP.NET (assuming there's a tool to do this) or the rendered HTML output; you still face the same challenges outlined above. Just one other thought though - Blend 3 can import directly from Illustrator so if you have .ai or .eps artwork from your designer this could fast track the process although I'd still have the same concerns about syntax quality.